# Change ui-grid row selection in execution time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to disable the row selection on my ui-grid when a condition is reached.

Example: I have a master/slave grid. When i'm adding a new record on the slave, i want to disable the row selection on masters grid.

I tried to change the properties:

```
scope.gridOptions.enableFullRowSelection =  false;  
scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection =  false;
```

But the grid is still selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);` in order for the change to be effective.

You can see it in use in [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection).

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback dude! It works, thank you bro!